# Ajax request using two arrays

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have two arrays. Both are getting from two different $.each() functions.

```
var firstArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']; // **Dynamic Values
var counter = 0;
$.each(function(i, v){

  //some code....
  secondArray[counter]  = $(this).val();

  //secondArray have these values ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']

  counter++;
  if(counter >= 4){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: customURL,
      data: ?????
    });
  } 
});
```

Actually i want the result like the 'item1' will get the 'value1', 'item2' to 'value2' and so on. In past when i used static values like -

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: customURL,
  data: {
    'item1' : value[0],
    'item2' : value[1],
    'item2' : value[2],
    'item3' : value[3],
   }

});
```

i got the results using these static values but how could i use dynamic values instead of 'item1', 'item2' and so on. Remember the 'firstArray' values are dynamic means they can be changed. I am using only jQuery and HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
var firstArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']; // **Dynamic Values
var secondArray = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'];
var ajaxData = {}; // initial declaration with empty object

$.each(firstArray , function(i, v){

      ajaxData[firstArray[i]]   = secondArray[i];

});

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: customURL,
      data: ajaxData,
}).done(function(result){
      //do something after success
});
```

Check out this fiddle for your ease: https://jsfiddle.net/syamsoul/zuncrx8q/4

Comment: Thanks, @Syamsoul ... by assigning arrays to an empty array 'ajaxData' i got the solution. I was doing this before but don't know why it was not executing the result.

Answer (score 2):

you only can send one data set with one request. so perhaps it's an option for you to merge your set before

**Just sample code**

```
let firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let secondArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let dataSet = {
  first: firstarray, 
  second: secondArray
};

$.ajax({
  url: customUrl,
  method: 'POST',
  accepts: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: dataSet
})
  .done((res, status, xhr) => {
    // whatever you need to do
  })
  .fail((xhr, status, state) => {
    // whatever you need to do
  });
```

after that you have to handle the two arrays at backend

Comment: Your answer is correct **but how does it answer the OP question?**

Comment: @mtizziani ...Although, this is correct way but not for this question.